# If $f:X \rightarrow \Bbb{K}$ is a linear functional,then $\textbf{Ker}(f)$ is a maximal subspace of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a linear functional on vector space $X$.

$K$ is a Field which can be $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$.

Let $Z(f)$ denote the kernel of $f$

The Maximal subspace of $f$ :

$Z$ is said to be a maximal subspace of $X$ if for any subspace $Z_{1}$ with $Z \subset Z_{1} \subset X$ then either $Z = Z_{1}$ or $X = Z_{1}$

definition 2 :

$Z$ is a maximal subspace of $X$ $\textbf{iff}$ $\textbf{span}(Z \cup \{a\}) = X$ for any $a \in X\setminus Z$.

For $f$ a linear functional on $X$. Now I was thinking to prove that $Z(f)$ is a maximal subspace of $X$.

For proving I thought of this- Suppose $Z \neq Z_{1}$ then we need to show that $Z_{1} = X$,but how do I proceed with this?

$\textbf{EDIT}:$

Also as pointed out in the comments whether $X$ is finite dimensional or infinite dimensional? So it would be interesting to see if those two case go similarly or are there any different treatment or consequences in the proof of both the cases?

Any help is great.

Comment: Assume $f(x)\neq0$. Then, if $z$ is any vector of $X$, we can write $z=\frac{f(z)}{f(x)}x+\left(z-\frac{f(z)}{f(x)}x\right)$. Notice that the second term is in the kernel and the first is generated by $x$. Therefore the kernel and $x$ generate the whole space.

Comment: Use the dimensions theorem: $\dim X/Z=\dim\operatorname{Im} f$.

Comment: In the title, you write $f : X \to X$ is a functional; did you mean $f: X \to \Bbb R$? Also, are you assuming that your vector space is finite-dimensional? And finally, what does $a \in X/Z$ mean? I'd say that in this case, $a$ is a coset of $Z$, so $\{a\}$ is a set containing a coset, hence not really eligible to be an argument to "span".

Comment: Nice observation that $x$ and $Ker(f)$ generate the whole space $X$,Now I am thinking how that aids in showing that $Ker(f)$ is a maximal subspace of $X$ @NinaSimone

Comment: Man, really? If $Z\supset Ker(f)$ and $x\in Z$ but not in $Ker(f)$, i.e. $f(x)\neq0$ then $Z$ contains the span of $x$ and $Ker(f)$. Since that span is the whole space then $Z$ contains the whole space.

Comment: Ok I think you are using second definition of maximal subspace, that is $Span(Ker(f) \cup \{ x \}) = X$,but i think we have not stressed on $x \in X / Ker(f)$,Ok gotcha @NinaSimone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nina Simone gave already the way for the proof which is independent of the dimension of $X$. I just improve the argument.

> $Z$ is said to be a maximal subspace of $X$ if for any subspace $Z_1$ with $Z\subset Z_1\subset X$ then either $Z_1=Z$ or $Z_1=X$.

It is a little bit more comfortable to use

> $Z$ is said to be a maximal subspace of $X$ if for any subspace $Z_1$ with $Z\subsetneq Z_1\subseteq X$ holds $Z_1=X$.

Let us consider $z\in Z_1\setminus Z\neq \emptyset$. We get $f(z)\neq 0$ since $z\notin Z$. For each $x\in X$ we can write
$$
x=\underbrace{\frac{f(x)}{f(z)}z}_{\in Z_1}+\underbrace{\left(x-\frac{f(x)}{f(z)}z\right)}_{\in Z}
$$
since $f\left(x-\frac{f(x)}{f(z)}z\right)=0$. From $Z\subseteq Z_1$ we conclude $x\in Z_1$. Since $x\in X$ was arbitrary we conclude $X\subseteq Z_1$ and therefore $Z_1=X$.

Comment: Thanks but I think in the last but above line $Z \subsetneq Z_{1}$?

Comment: You can change $\subseteq$ to $\subsetneq$ if you feel better. But for that argument, $\subseteq$ is sufficient, which is just weaker than $\subsetneq$.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are completely fine. Nonetheless, I would like to add one that demonstrate the power of normalization.

Let $f$ be a linear functional and $Z$ a subspace of $X$ such that $\ker(f)\subsetneq Z$. We would like to claim that $Z = X$. We pick $z\in Z\backslash X$ with $f(z)\neq 0$ and pick $x\in X$ with $f(x)\neq 0$; we want to show $x\in Z$.

Now we split things into cases:

We first consider $f(z) = f(x) = 1$. Then it follows clearly by linearity that $z-x\in \ker(f)$. It follows clearly that $x \in \langle\{z\}\rangle\oplus \ker(f)\subset Z$.

The general case, as is demonstrated by other answers, is just an application of the first case by replacing $x$ with $x/f(x)$ and $z$ with $z/f(z)$.